# Which actionscript / flash framework has the best tools for simple animation

Tags: flash, actionscript

I'm converting some Flex down to an Actionscript project and need to get up to speed as quickly as possible on a lightweight framwork for doing basic animation.

The components may have some very simple data access - such as reading a list of images, but nothing clever.

What I really want is an equivalent of Flex's 'AnimateProperty' or 'Move'. Yes very simple!

I just don't want to have to go too low level and start doing `x+=` in an `onEnterFrame()` event handler. I just want to replace timeline based animation with object oriented script.

Answer (score 2):

I like `caurina` which is easy to use but able to handle really complex things. It can be found [here](http://code.google.com/p/tweener/). But the best is just to grap a few and test them yourself.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** Changed my mind about gTween. See my other post below/above.

Its still in Beta but I'm liking the look of [gTween](http://www.gskinner.com/libraries/gtween/)

> GTween is a light-weight instance
>   oriented tween engine. This means that
>   you instantiate tweens for specific
>   purposes, and then reuse, update or
>   discard them. This is different than
>   centralized tween engines where you
>   "register" tweens with a global
>   object. This provides a more familiar
>   and useful interface for object
>   oriented programmers.

[This doc](http://www.gskinner.com/libraries/gtween/docs/com/gskinner/motion/GTween.html) actually gives a better overview that the main gTween page.

Answer (score 0):

Oops. it pretty much looks like gTween is being discontinued and [the author is now working  collaboratively](http://blog.greensock.com/gskinnercollaboration/) with the author of '[TweenLite / TweenMax](http://blog.greensock.com/tweenliteas3/)', which now has some cool pseudo-timeline based animation abilities.

I've switched to that now.